# Excel VBA Run Time Error '13' type mismatch on worksheet variable

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I keep getting getting the the 'type mismatch' error mentioned above when trying to set my 'remSheet' variable to sheet1 of the newQuery workbook. 
The beginning of the script is shown below. The last line is the line that causes the error

```
Sub importNewPTRs()
Dim masterWorkbook As Workbook
Set masterWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Dim newQuery As Workbook
Set newQuery = openWorkbook
Set newQuery = ActiveWorkbook
Dim remSheet As Worksheet
Set remSheet = Sheets(Sheet1)
```

I have looked at solutions to other issues with this particular error message and they have not helped. I have also tried setting remSheet = newQuery.Sheets(Sheet1) and that has not help either. 
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Set remSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")` you need to identify by name, not codename.

Comment: It would be good practice to also declare the parent workbook when setting the sheet: `Set remSheet = masterWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` or `Set remSheet = newQuery.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use the sheet position `Index` (If it's the first sheet `1`, second sheet `2`...) or the `Name` as it appears in the tab. your `Sheet1` variable isn't anything and is causing your error.

Comment: Actually, `Sheet1` is the default CodeName for the first worksheet but it isn't used like the OP used it.

Comment: @Jeeped you are correct. That's why I suggested using either Index or Name property. There's always more than 1 way to get something done.